# What is the longest distance between a noun in an oblique case and the verb that it attaches to?

Tags: linguistics

What is the longest distance between a noun in an oblique case and the verb that it attaches to, in classical writings?

If you can find and post an example sentence to illustrate how many words that distance can stretch, that would be great.

I'm asking because I'm wondering if Roman authors took measures to avoid overflowing the reader's working memory, even when writing the very long sentences of the kind that Latin makes possible.

Of course, if you know of any notable sentences or teachings regarding distance between oblique noun and verb from medieval, renaissance, or later writings, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: I would say there is no limit. I have seen plenty of sentences beginning with an object and ending with the verb. They didn't seem to care about our poor brain's overload!

Comment: The sentences people will _write_ can be very different from the sentences they'll _say_. I suspect you'll find a much higher distance in writing.